# Error creating DigitalOcean droplet using docker-machine

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

Not sure if it's a DigitalOcean problem or `docker-machine` but I get this error repeatedly while trying to create a droplet on DO

```
$ docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=$TOKEN --digitalocean-region=sgp1 --digitalocean-image=ubuntu-14-04-x64 --digitalocean-size "1gb" staging
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(staging) Creating SSH key...
(staging) Creating Digital Ocean droplet...
(staging) Waiting for IP address to be assigned to the Droplet...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(upstart)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: Get https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/17900941: dial tcp: lookup api.digitalocean.com on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:40376->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout
```

I am using following docker packages on Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.7.0, build a650a40

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:47:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 00:34:20 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I solved the problem as following.
I was developing in virtualbox machine and I ran the command when I started work

```
eval "$(docker-machine env local)"
```

So my docker-machine `env` was set to some variables, because of which running `docker-machine create` in the same terminal was causing DNS resolution problem.

Just **started a new terminal** and was able to create a DigitalOcean droplet without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Error is: `read udp 127.0.0.1:40376->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout`

Looks like its trying to use localhost as the nameserver and no DNS server is running.
What is your `/etc/resolv.conf` file looking like?

Two ways to fix this: bring up the DNS server on the local box or, the better way, fix your DNS server setup in that file and use e.g. `8.8.8.8` as the nameserver.

Comment: My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this - `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
`

Comment: It says don't change this file, your changes will be overwritten! What's the proper way to fix this file?

Comment: I think I figured it out, your comment definitely pointed me in the right direction. Upvoting and adding the answer below for the reference